# python-oracledb got error when using oracle's vector type

Tags: oracle, vector, python-oracledb

I'm trying to get hands on Oracle's new vector type on version 23.4.

I'm using python-oracledb but I got an error:

> has no attribute of DB_TYPE_VECTOR

Am I running the wrong version of python-oracledb? I just installed it with `pip install oracledb`. Could you show me the ropes?

I've checked the oracledb code on Github but it seems there is no `DB_TYPE_VECTOR` there.

Answer (score 0):

This is available in version 2.1.0 of the python-oracledb driver which was just released on PyPI (March 11, 2024).